# zsh: command not found: "ams_cds"

Tags: ssh, terminal, zsh, zshrc, cadence

I am trying to get my Cadence Environment set up for designing my circuit. This is my first encounter with .zshrc files. I am working from my school server. I was instructed to run the command `zsh`  first and then basically run this command:

```
ams_cds -tech h35b4 -mode fb`
```

(specific to Cadence design kit). On running this, I get the following error:

```
zsh: command not found : ams_cds
```

I have been trying to resolve this "command not found" issue but have not succeded in doing so. Any help/guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure why "run zsh" is part of the instructions, but your problem is that whatever directory contains `ams_cds` isn't in your path.